# How to attach a piece of paper to a paper surface that has been embossed

Tags: adhesives

So I was trying to attach a piece of paper covered in hot glue to an embossed paper surface with hot glue, and it just kept falling off. Is there a better glue or better method to attach the paper to the embossed surface? Just to be clear, the paper surface was embossed with clear embossing powder, so it is shiny, smooth and pretty much impermeable. I am up for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What material is the embossed surface made of? I assume paper as well, but you don't specify it.

Comment: Can clear embossing powder itself be used as a glue?

Comment: How large a surface are you trying to glue?  How strong and how permanent does the attachment need to be?  Will there be exposed edges or corners that can catch and get peeled up?  Is the embossed surface a smooth, uniform layer of embossing medium or irregular?  If the surface is irregular, do you care if that translates through the attached paper?  What kind of paper are you trying to attach (something thick and stiff like kraft paper)?  How are you applying the hot glue (describe the procedure)--just squirting some lines or swirls around the paper or spreading a smooth layer?  (cont'd)

Comment: How are you keeping the glue and surfaces hot until the paper is in place?  Have you tried heating both surfaces with a heat gun, applying the paper, then ironing the back of the paper with a hot iron?  As csk suggested, have you tried remelting the embossing medium with a heat gun and pressing the paper onto it?

Comment: @csk I will try reheating the embossing surface

Comment: OhWin, can you let us know whether or not it worked? You can answer your question yourself if it did, and, if not, update your question and get more advice in the form of answers or comments.